# SUMO with TraCI, getting OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: winapi, subprocess, sumo, traffic-simulation

Trying to run the SUMO simulation using TraCI protocol:

```py
import os, sys
if 'SUMO_HOME' in os.environ:
    tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME'], 'tools')
    sys.path.append(tools)
else:
    sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME'")

sumoBinary = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Thesis_task/Trial_task/trial.sumocfg"
sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", "trial.sumocfg", '--log', 'logfile.txt'] 

import traci
traci.start(sumoCmd)
step = 0
while step < 1000:
    traci.simulationStep()
    if traci.inductionloop.getLastStepVehicleNumber("0") > 0:
        traci.trafficlight.setRedYellowGreenState("0", "GrGr") 
    step += 1

traci.close()
```

I am trying to connect the TraCI, but it is throwing this error:

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I have installed all the dependencies correctly, and also have the supporting Python version running on my machine. I followed a few older StackOverflow solutions, but none of them worked in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the TraCI documentation:

[Interfacing TraCI from Python](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI/Interfacing_TraCI_from_Python.html)

> First you compose the command line to **start either [`sumo`](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/sumo.html) or [`sumo-gui`](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/sumo-gui.html)** (leaving out the option which was needed before 0.28.0):
>
> ```py
> sumoBinary = "/path/to/sumo-gui"
> sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", "yourConfiguration.sumocfg"]
> ```

However, your `sumoBinary` variable does not point to either of those two programs, instead it points to your `trial.sumocfg` file:

> ```py
> sumoBinary = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Thesis_task/Trial_task/trial.sumocfg"
> ```

Which is clearly not an executable program, hence the error.

Comment: I just modify my Python code to point to the actual SUMO executable instead of the configuration file.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation yet to upvote the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified my Python code to point out the actual SUMO executable instead of the configuration file.

```
sumoBinary = "sumo-gui"
sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", 
          "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Thesis_task/Trial_task/trial.sumocfg"]
```

Also added the SUMO bin directory to the system path so that it can be found by subprocess.

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "C:/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse/Sumo/bin"
```

Now I can at least launch the sumo-gui without error.
Thanks!